# std::stringstream efficient way to get written data, copy to another stream

Tags: c++

Without writing a custom rdbuf is there any way to use a stringstream efficiently?  That is, with these requirements:

- the stream can be reset and writing start again without deallocating previous memory
- get a const char* to the data written (along with the length) without creating a temporary
- populate the stream without creating a temporary string

If somebody can give me a definitive "no" that would be great.

Now, I also use boost, so if somebody can provide a boost alternative which does this that would be great. It *has* to have both istream and ostream interfaces available.

Comment: Always been wondering about this myself. Let's see what answers come up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [**`boost::interprocess::vectorstream` or `boost::interprocess::bufferstream`**](http://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/interprocess/streams.html).  These classes basically meet all of your requirements.

`boost::interprocess::vectorstream` won't return a `const char*`, but it will return a const reference to an internal container class, (like an internal vector), rather than returning a temporary string copy.  On the other hand, `boost::interprocess::bufferstream` will basically allow you to use any arbitrary buffer as an I/O stream, giving you complete control over memory allocation, so you can easily use a `char` buffer if you want.

These are both great classes, and wonderful replacements for `std::stringstream`, which, in my opinion, has always been hindered by the fact that it doesn't give you direct access to the internal buffer, resulting in the unnecessary creation of temporary string objects.  It's a shame these classes are somewhat obscure, hidden away in the interprocess library.

Comment: Great. Yeah, I never thought to look in the interprocess library. I'll try these out.